# How to find partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I have this equation

$$π =(1000 − y_1 − y_2)(y_1 + y_2) - y_1^2 - 200y_2 -y_2^2$$

which simplifies to

$$1000y_1 + 800y_2 − 2y_2^2 - 2y_1^2 - 2y_12y_2$$

Variables are $y_1$ and $y_2$

It says that the partial derivative with respect to $y_1 =1000 − 2y_2 − 4y_1$
But i cant seem to get this answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplification is wrong, you should not have a term like $2y_12y_2$.

\begin{align}
\pi &=(1000-y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2)-y_1^2-200y_2-y_2^2\\
&=1000y_1+1000y_2-y_1^2-y_1y_2-y_2y_1-y_2^2-y_1^2-200y_2-y_2^2\\
&=1000y_1+800y_2-2y_1^2-2y_1y_2-2y_2^2
\end{align}

Now take the partial derivative and you will get the answer.

Comment: You forgot to square your last term.

Comment: @mr_e_man good catch